# Continuous functions on the torus.

Tags: several-complex-variables

If $\varphi:\mathbb T^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb C$ is a continuous function of two variables on the torus, then the range of $\varphi$ is always a closed curve?

Comment: What is a "bi-torus"?

Comment: I am considering $\mathbb T$ the boundary of the unit disk $\mathbb D$ and $\mathbb T^{2}$ the cartesian product of 2 copies of $\mathbb T$.

Comment: Then that is simply the "torus".

Comment: Or maybe "2-torus", if you're in a context where you might be considering $\mathbb{T}^n$ for higher $n$. But yeah, I've never seen 'bi-torus' used before.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what you mean by a *curve*. For instance in some context of analytic--or differential--geometry a curve is a map
$$
f:I\longrightarrow \Bbb R^2
$$
where $I\subset\Bbb R$ is an interval (i.e. a curve is a   *function* not a *set*)

Or else, a curve may be thought as a $1$-dimensional real variety, whereas in an algebraic context a curve is often a $1$-dimensional complex variety.

In any event, consider that the torus is compact, so the image of your map is going to be a compact subset of $\Bbb C$, hence closed and bounded.

As an example, embed the torus in $\Bbb R^3$ so that $\Bbb R^2$ is identified to a plane splitting it in half transversally.

Now let $\varphi$ the function on the torus that is the projection from $\Bbb R^3$ to $\Bbb R^2$. Is the image a curve in any sense?

Comment: Hi Andrea Mori.
Sorry!
In fact, I am referring to a curve as a subset of $\mathbb C$. For instance, if $\gamma$ is a continuous complex-valued function on $\mathbb T$, then $\gamma$ is a closed curve (in the sense that the end point coincides with the start point). In this case, we can calculate the winding number of $\gamma$ about a point that is not in the range of $\gamma$. What I would like to know is if, in the case of continuous functions in bi-torus, we can have this same notion.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the most obvious definitions for the words, the answer is no.  A torus is a two-dimensional object.  Generally, the image will have two dimensions, so it will not be a curve.

Comment: To give an explicit example, lay a doughnut flat on the table, and flatten it. The image is an annulus.